# CIDepthBlurEffect, strange vertical lines appearing

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, core-image, cifilter

I managed to make focus effect by myself, but I found an another problem.
Every time I render photos with depth by CIDepthBlurEffect, strange vertical lines appear like this:

[image]

They always appear in the same place, on top of the photo.

Do you know how to solve this?
Please give me your idea.

Edit: I leave the code that I have a issue with.
Sorry for a messy code.

depth photo

```
//getting depth data
func getdepth(with data: Data, guide: CIImage) -> CIImage?{

let processedimage = CIImage(data: data, options: [
  CIImageOption.nearestSampling: false,
  CIImageOption.auxiliaryDisparity: true,
  //CIImageOption.auxiliaryDepth: true,
  CIImageOption.applyOrientationProperty: true
  ])

if let depth = processedimage?.upsample(guide: guide){
  return depth
}

return processedimage
}

//upsample

extension CIImage{

  func upsample(guide: CIImage) -> CIImage?{

    //let trans = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: self.extent.width /     guide.extent.width, y: self.extent.height / guide.extent.height)

   //let guider = guide.transformed(by: trans)

   guard let filter = CIFilter(name: "CIEdgePreserveUpsampleFilter") else { return nil }
 filter.setValue(self, forKey: "inputSmallImage")
 filter.setValue(guide, forKey: kCIInputImageKey)

 return filter.outputImage

  }
}

//main image

guard let image = CIImage(data: data, options:
  [CIImageOption.applyOrientationProperty: true]
  ) else { return }



//input variable: main: CIImage, depth: CIImage, matte: CIImage?

let transform = CGAffineTransform(
  scaleX: main.extent.width / combined.extent.width,
  y: main.extent.height / combined.extent.height
)

let depthscaled = depth.transformed(by: transform)

var applyingdepth: CIFilter!

if let mat = matte{

  if #available(iOS 12.0, *) {
    applyingdepth = CIFilter(name: "CIDepthBlurEffect", parameters: [
      kCIInputImageKey: main,
      kCIInputDisparityImageKey: depthscaled,
      kCIInputMatteImageKey: mat

      ])!

  }
}else {

  applyingdepth = CIFilter(name: "CIDepthBlurEffect", parameters: [
    kCIInputImageKey: main,
    kCIInputDisparityImageKey: depthscaled

    ])!

}

applyingdepth.setValue(1.4, forKey: "inputAperture")

return applying depth.output // this is "portraitimage"

//outside of this block
 guard let portrait = context.createCGImage(portraitimage, from: portraitimage.extent) else { return }

  UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(UIImage(cgImage: portrait), nil, nil, nil)
```

Comment: It would be helpful for us if you'd post some code. Maybe add the input image so we could reproduce your issue. Thanks.

Comment: Ok. I posted the code. I hope it helps reconstructing the issue.And thank you.